# truffle init node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle

**I wanted to create my own NFT collection so I bought a course called "The Complete NFT Web Development Course - Zero To Expert
". In that course you need to use truffle. I installed all what I sopposed to need but when I try to type truffle init it gives me an error. I used npm install also in this process and it gaves me an error related to react, but I don't think that it's the problem. I have a package.json downloaded from the github repositorie that the teacher have.**

**Versions:**

npm: '8.3.1',
node: '16.14.0'
Windows 10

**Error:**
truffle init
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)[39m
[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47[39m {
code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
requireStack: []
}

Comment: have you tried deleting the `package.json` and downloading each single dependency?

Comment: no, i will try that thanks

Comment: I solved it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling truffle. If you reinstall truffle you will get upgraded version. And that might solve your problem.

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that i didn't install Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Installing truffle version 5.4.29 `install -g truffle@5.4.29` in the command prompt and got a message to run `npm audit fix --force`.
Then inside vscode inside terminal I ran `truffle init` and got the "sweet " message. I suppose the version matters.